# Python Kernel fails to start in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio, tornado

I have been working with Jupyter on my Windows PC for a long time with no issues. While opening Jupyter yesterday, the main window in the web browser opens but the kernel fails to start when I try and create a new file.

This part works fine and opens jupyter a browser window

```
PS C:\Users\ntink> jupyter notebook

[I 10:03:02.983 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from c:\users\ntink\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 10:03:02.984 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\ntink\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\share\jupyter\lab
[I 10:03:02.993 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\ntink
[I 10:03:02.993 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.0 is running at:
[I 10:03:02.994 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=df916b72450995d42810037217ca24867ee6e88b1b607e16
[I 10:03:02.995 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=df916b72450995d42810037217ca24867ee6e88b1b607e16
[I 10:03:02.996 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 10:03:03.101 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/ntink/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-8220-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=df916b72450995d42810037217ca24867ee6e88b1b607e16
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=df916b72450995d42810037217ca24867ee6e88b1b607e16
```

But while creating a new Python3 notebook, the kernel fails

```
[I 10:03:18.232 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 10:03:21.248 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 7a3a78c5-504b-48bc-b561-43dc9b9823b0, name: python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ntink\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\ntink\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\users\ntink\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "c:\users\ntink\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "c:\users\ntink\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "c:\users\ntink\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "c:\users\ntink\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 314, in run_forever
    assert self._self_reading_future is None
AssertionError
```

I was suspecting that an upgraded package was causing this and I tried reinstalling jupyter and its dependecnies, asyncio and tornado but to no avail. I am getting a similar kernel error when I try and open existing jupyter notebooks.

Here are the details of the installed packages. Thanks in advance, I have not been able to figure this out and it's driving me crazy.

```
Package Version
async-generator 1.1
asyncio 3.4.3
jenkinsapi  0.3.9
Jinja2  2.9.4
jupyter-client  6.1.12
jupyter-core    4.7.1
jupyterlab  0.35.4
jupyterlab-pygments 0.1.2
jupyterlab-server   0.2.0
nbclient    0.5.3
nbconvert   6.1.0
nbformat    5.1.3
notebook    6.4.0
pip 21.1.3
terminado   0.10.1
tornado 6.1
```

Comment: did you try recreating the kernel ?

Comment: Yes but am getting the same error when I try opening a new file. Or did you mean reinstalling the kernel?

Comment: I tried reinstalling ipykernel with pip install -U ipykernel and this fixed this issue. Thanks @heretolearn